# Fixing Error Code 40000. SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I am trying to create a simple application that will be run locally from Net-beans, but it gives me an error every time I try to do a database operation.

> [EL Info]: 2015-10-25 09:48:21.192--ServerSession(26304643)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
>   [EL Severe]: 2015-10-25 09:48:23.42--ServerSession(26304643)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
>   Error Code: 40000
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.

I am only performing a simple query in this case

```
   private void btnSelectLastActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String last = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the student's last name");

    Query q = GeoBeeAppPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELCT t FROM tblStudentsList WHERE t.lastname = ?1 ORDER BY t.firstname");
    q.setParameter(1,last );

    List<Tblstudents> LastList = q.getResultList();

    tblstudentsList2.clear();
    tblstudentsList2.addAll(LastList);
```

And this is the persistance xml:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"      
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="GeoBeeAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>org.me.mybackgroundapp.Tblstudents</class>
<class>org.me.mybackgroundapp.Tblstudentscores</class>
<class>org.me.mybackgroundapp.Tblquizquestions</class>
<class>org.me.mybackgroundapp.Tblteachers</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GeoBee_DB"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
</properties>
```

Comment: There is nothing running on port 1527, or it was rejected by a firewall. Check if 1) derby is running and 2) it is running on port 1527.

Comment: If you're using NetBeans IDE, then you can start the database by going to Services tab -> Databases -> right click Java DB -> Start Server.